# Web.xml content for Perl application on Tomcat

Tags: perl, tomcat, xampp, web.xml

I have a Perl application which I am moving from the Apache server to the Tomcat server in xampp 7.1.7.  I have followed the following:

- http://www.wellho.net/forum/Perl-Programming/Running-Perl-CGI-scripts-under-Apache-Tomcat.html
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html

And one tiny detail is eluding me.  What is the content of the web.xml in the webapps/project_name/WEB-INF supposed to look like?  There is no java servlet.  This is 100% Perl.  The reason I'm running it under Tomcat is that my SSO authentication runs as an authentication filter configured in the application web.xml file.

Comment: From what I understand from that forum is that you need to use the servlet that's already there in the web.xml file. But then that post is over 10 years old. Stuff might have changed.

Comment: There are two web.xml files in play.  The one in tomcat/conf is set up with the servlet 'cgi' pointing to the class CGIServlet.  I'm talking about the web application's specific web.xml, the one located in tomcat/webapps/project_name/WEB-INF.  Should that reference the same servlet?

Comment: Based on both links I don't think you actually need that second file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simbabque's response was right on target.  I DO need the application-specific web.xml, for other reasons, so the answer was to move the <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> tags from the conf/web.xml to the application-specific WEB-INF/web.xml.